# No sound after installing Ubuntu 18.10 on a Hp Chromebook 14 (KIP)

Tags: chromebook, 18.10

I really want to install Ubuntu 18.10 on my Hp Chromebook 14, everything is working fine and smoothly but the audio. There is no audio and can't find a solution.

I'll really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Does not work on Lenovo Thinkpad neither!**

ls -l /dev/snd

totalt 0

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 okt 25 13:42 seq

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 okt 25 13:42 timer

lspci -v gives:

0:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

```
Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio

Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 133

Memory at f1340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

Memory at f1330000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]

Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3

Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+

Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

aplay -L:

default

```
Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
```

null

```
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
```

pulse

```
PulseAudio Sound Server
```

Comment: After an upgrade this weekend the sound is back :)